# Should I mention that I refereed a paper in my CV/SOP?

Tags: graduate-admissions, peer-review, cv, statement-of-purpose

The journal I published in invited me to referee a paper and I would like to know if such experience can can be mentioned in my CV/SOP when I apply for masters/PhD degree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it can be mentioned. I would put a category on your CV titled "service to the profession." In that section, mention the year and the name of the journal that asked you to referee. It's not a major point, but it shows that you're willing to be a team player and help out the journal. That speaks both to your professionalism and to the fact that the editor trusted your judgment.

Comment: Thanks Shane for the help. Great answer and great suggestion !